# Google sheet SendEmail Script send a message to the same email address multiple times/ It hasn't happened untill today. Any way To solve it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Stack overflowers!

I have a problem with my Sendemail Script, which is sending the same message for 8 times (really annoying, isn't it?) to each mail address. (It has been working fine until today though, I send remainders to five people daily; and my google sheet has two columns, one is for email address and the other is the message)

My code looks like this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 5; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B6
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[I];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'ATTENTION!!!!!!';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

How can I solve this annoying problem? (I am not a developer; I am just a learner who can use internet sources very well; So, I don't understand scripts much and still can edit or change it a bit.)

Comment: You say "It has been working fine until today": Does the script run on trigger? I assume by `var row = data[I];` you mean `var row = data[i];` and all of your rows have different contents?

Comment: @ziganotschka Yes, it runs on daily trigger. That is right. it is var row = data[i].  All the rows have differrent email addresses, but the same reminder message.

Answer (score 0):

### There is currently a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/157080185) with time-driven triggers

As a consequence, the trigger might fire multiple times - more frequent than you specify.

You can "star" the issue on Google's Issue Tracker to indicate that you are also concerned.

In the meantime, as a workaround:

- Use [Script Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties) to save the last execution time
- Implement an `if` statement at the beginning of your code that executes the rest of the code only if the last execution time (retrieved from the script properties) is not less than the specified interval

Sample:

```
function sendEmails() {
  if(!PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("lastExecution")){
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("lastExecution", new Date().getTime());
  }
  var lastExecution = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("lastExecution");
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var oneDay = 1000*3600*24;
  if(now-lastExecution >= oneDay){
    //here the rest of you code
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 5; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B6
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i in data) {
      var row = data[I];
      var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
      var message = row[1]; // Second column
      var subject = 'ATTENTION!!!!!!';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("lastExecution", now);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code. But it didn't work. I tried it with minute-based trigger. Anyway,thanks. Could it be a server-related problem? I send the reminders to mail addresses on our webmailserver/

Comment: What exactly did not work about the code? The problem with time-driven triggers themselves is as I mentioned a bug from Google's side. Many people have recently the same problem like you, so I hope Google will fix the problem soon. But if you need a temporarily solution for the meantime, the code above should actually work. Just that if you have a 2-minuts trigger instead of a dayly trigger like in the sample, you should change `var twoMinutes = 1000*60*2;` to `var oneDay = 1000*3600*24;` Mind you, do you really want to send the emails each 2 minutes?This would result in multiple emails...

Comment: It didn't work because I hadn't changed " var oneDay = 1000*3600*24 " / Now I understand it. Thank you